# Some doubts regarding HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

`HashMap` is implemented in a very simpe manner but it needs a genius to understand how it is implemented. So, I have read about `HashMap` in java docs. I have some small questions regarding `HashMap`:

1. I know default capacity of `HashMap` is 16. In java docs they have given **The default initial capacity - MUST be a power of two.**. Any specific reason behind this?
2. I know a little bit how `HashMap` works on basis of HashCode, Bucket and `LinkedList` if i am not wrong. Then how size of `HashMap` is being increased. I mean how buckets size and LinkedList size are managed.
3. This might be silly question. When we add new element in `HashMap`, on basis of HashCode it directly access that particular bucket without traveling like in `LinkedList`. Am I right? And other thing is that it adds element at head not at tails. What is the reason for that. Is new element added at head of `LinkedList` present inside bucket to avoid tail traversing. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: [Best explanation ever](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-internal).

Comment: @Maroun Maroun  +1 for link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using powers of two simplifies the implementation and improves its performance.
   E.g. to find a bucket from a hash code it can use hash & (SIZE -1) instead of abs(hash) % SIZE
2. Until you know how `HashMap`  works exactly you won't be able to answer this question. If the size of the Map exceeds a given threshold defined by load-factor e.g. if load factor is .75 it will act to re-size the map once it filled 75%. Similar to other collection classes like `ArrayList`,  Java `HashMap` re-size itself by creating a new bucket array of size twice of previous size of `HashMap` , and then start putting every old element into that new bucket array. This process is called rehashing because it also applies hash function to find new bucket location.
3. We store every new element at the head of the linked list to avoid tail traversing and hence at the time of resizing the entire sequence of objects in linked list gets reversed, during which there are chances of infinite loops.

Read more here:

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-internal
- http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

Answer (score 2):

1. The reason for making the capacity a power of 2 is (I think) mostly to simplify the code.  There is a small performance advantage, but it is close to negligible.
2. It goes like this:

   - A HashMap is expanded when you attempt to add a new entry.  It occurs (roughly speaking) when `map.size() * load_factor > array.length`. (Refer to the code for the precise details.)
   - When a HashMap is expanded, the array is doubled in size.  There is a hard limit ... imposed by the size of arrays in Java.  After that, the HasMap's array doesn't expand.  (Instead, you just get longer and longer hash chains ...)
   - Nothing is done to manage the lengths of the individual hash chains.  Instead, when the HashMap expands, the entries in each old chain are moved to the respective chains in the expanded table.  (At least in recent implementations, each chain node holds a cached hash value for the entry, so there is *no need to reevaluate the hash functions* during the table expansion.)
3. Basically, yes and yes.  New entries get added to the start of each hashchain because that is the most efficient (time and space-wise) to do it.  Since the order of the elements in a hash chain do not signify anything, there is no point in inserting new entries at the tail of the chain.  This also means that in a typical HashMap implementation, expanding the table reverses the order of hash chain entries.

---

Note that the actual behaviour and actual implementation details for `HashMap` differ for different releases of Java.  The only way to be sure is to read the source code for the version of Java that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would assume that the power of two requirement is there to speed up picking buckets. If you have 16 buckets and an index of 578123 or something, you can use a simple AND to pick a bucket instead of having to calculate 578123 mod 16, which is slower.
2. `HashMap` has a load factor, which is 0.75 by default. If the amount of objects > amount of buckets * load factor, the HashMap's capacity is increased to preserve performance. I would assume it simply doubles the amount of buckets and reassigns all elements.
3. Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand this question properly.